# Angular 1 button instead of 3

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with this pagination code. I have 1 button instead of 3. Can you help?

**paginator.js**

```
$scope.generateButtons = function () {
        var buttons = [],
            pageCount = getPageCount(),
            buttonCount;


        console.log("page " + pageCount);

        buttonCount = pageCount > 2 ? 3 : pageCount;

        for (var i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
            var index = +$scope.offset + i -1;
            if (index > 0) {
                buttons.push(index);
            }
        };

        return buttons;
    };
```

[View in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e7OoibDzHlXXHvtM8D1b)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Angular UI bootstrap pagination, and not write it from scratch https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PaginationDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {
  $scope.totalItems = 64;
  $scope.currentPage = 4;

  $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
  };

  $scope.pageChanged = function() {
    $log.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
  };

  $scope.maxSize = 5;
  $scope.bigTotalItems = 175;
  $scope.bigCurrentPage = 1;
});
```

Comment: I dont wont to use  Angular UI bootstrap pagination, because I wat to learn basic:)

Answer (score 0):

It's really not about angular related problem. Its all about the logic for `$scope.generateButtons = function () {...}`  Please change your logic as you need. Here is your code (edited) for displaying 3 buttons.

```
    $scope.generateButtons = function () {
        var buttons = [],
            pageCount = getPageCount(),
            buttonCount;

        buttonCount = pageCount > 2 ? 3 : pageCount;

        for (var i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
            var index = parseInt($scope.offset) + i+1;

            if (index >= 0) { // this `if` is not really needed
                buttons.push(index);
            }
        };

        return buttons;
    };
```

Enjoy!